# Trying to create a drop-down menu that displays options when the button is pressed

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a drop down menu, that when you press the "Select" button two options drop down. I want these options to be a Timesheet button and Expense report button. I can't get it to work, here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var SelectBTN: UIButton!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    @IBAction func handleSelection(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        SelectBTN.ForEach { (button) in
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                button.isHidden = !button.isHidden
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
            
        }
        

    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func cityTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func ERBTNpressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ERSegue", sender: self)
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func TSBTNpressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "TSSegue", sender: self)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are all those blank lines in the code really necessary? If not consider editing the post trimming some of those blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a menu as a primary action for a button in `viewDidLoad`:

```
SelectBTN.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
SelectBTN.menu = buttonMenu()
```

In the menu you could add actions:

```
func buttonMenu() -> UIMenu {
    let ERAction = UIAction(title: "Expense report", image: nil) { (_) in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ERSegue", sender: self)
    }
    
    let TSAction = UIAction(title: "Timesheet", image: nil) { (_) in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "TSSegue", sender: self)
    }
    
    return UIMenu(title: "", options: .displayInline, children: [ERAction, TSAction])
}
```

You could also add images to actions and specify attributes (i.e. `.destructive` for Delete action)